# Type 'HTMLInputElement' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: html, typescript

I am trying to perform a mouseover event in typescript. But showing an error as "Type 'HTMLInputElement' is not assignable to type 'string'" Here is my source code:

HTML:

```
<button class="close" id="mOver" mat-button onmouseover="mouseOver()">X</button>
```

Typescript:

```
export class InputComponent {
mouseOverValue = '';

mouseOver = () => {
     this.mouseOverValue = document.getElementById('mOver') as HTMLInputElement;
     this.mouseOverValue="Remove";
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want `mouseOverValue` to represent: The actual element `#mOver`, or one of `mOver`'s properties? And when you're setting `mouseOverValue` to "Remove", what specifically are you trying to have happen to `mOver` or another variable?

Comment: @JeffBowman I Have a button "x". I want to show a massage 'Remove' whenever I take my mouse over the button. I tried to pass the value "Remove" through mouseOverValue. Don't know if it is write approach or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// does not work 
this.mouseOverValue = document.getElementById('mOver') as HTMLInputElement;
```

```
const elem = document.getElementById('mOver') as HTMLInputElement;
this.mouseOverValue = elem.value;
```

```
const elem = document.getElementById('mOver') as HTMLInputElement;
this.mouseOverValue = 'remove';
elem.value = this.mouseOvervalue;
```

```
const elem = document.getElementById('mOver') as HTMLInputElement;
elem.value = 'remove';
this.mouseOverValue = elem.value;
```

mouseOverValue is must be string type
not asign HTMLInputElement type